# DH Key Exchange

Tags: diffie-hellman

I am trying to implement DH using Python (for tests), and its working for

(3 ^ random_number) mod 17

In order to be secure, the prime (in this case, 17) needs to be very long.

My question is: Where can i find secure primes and primitive roots to make the algoritym secure? As long as i know, generating these numbers requires a lot of computational power and time, and do not increases the security significantly.

I also have seen some standart quations in order to get secure numbers, but i have no Idea how to implement them Python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3526#page-3) lists a bunch of more or less standard parameters.

Comment: I already have seen this document, but i do not know how should i use these equations. Example: 2^3072 - 2^3008 - 1 + 2^64 * { [2^2942 pi] + 1690314 }  -How can i implement this in Python? Why it does not simply gives the number?

Comment: You mean why doesn't it have something like "Its hexadecimal value is:", followed by the actual value?

Comment: I have tried to decode to get the number, but all websites were not able to do it. Should i just place the equation there (with the correct operators) as the prime number and let it solve the equation? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

It worked fine with "5809605995369958062791915965639201402176612226902900533702900882779736177890990861472094774477339581147373410185646378328043729800750470098210924487866935059164371588168047540943981644516632755067501626434556398193186628990071248660819361205119793693985433297036118232914410171876807536457391277857011849897410207519105333355801121109356897459426271845471397952675959440793493071628394122780510124618488232602464649876850458861245784240929258426287699705312584509625419513463605155428017165714465363094021609290561084025893662561222573202082865797821865270991145082200656978177192827024538990239969175546190770645685893438011714430426409338676314743571154537142031573004276428701433036381801705308659830751190352946025482059931306571004727362479688415574702596946457770284148435989129632853918392117997472632693078113129886487399347796982772784615865232621289656944284216824611318709764535152507354116344703769998514148343807"

Thank you!